# How do I make an FTP connection from a module?

Tags: 8, files

I'm trying to create a custom module that would connect to an external FTP and grab an XML file (provided by third party). This file can't be accessed through http.

In Drupal 8, there is the [`Drupal\Core\FileTransfer\FTP`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!FileTransfer!FTP.php/class/FTP/8.2.x) class, but I'm not sure as of how I could use it inside my custom module. I don't see any service I could use.

Do I use that class directly, or is there a service I need to use?

Answer (score 1):

The information about the classes that extends `FileTransfer()` are returned from [`hook_filetransfer_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21File%21file.api.php/function/hook_filetransfer_info/8.2.x), and altered by [`hook_filetransfer_info_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21File%21file.api.php/function/hook_filetransfer_info_alter/8.2.x). There isn't any service to use.
As such, the code that uses that class should be similar to the following one.

```
$info = drupal_get_filetransfer_info();

if (!empty($info['ftp']) && $class = $info['ftp']['class']) {
  $ftp = $class::factory($jail, $settings);
}
```

Notice that when the patch in [Convert hook_filetransfer_info() to plugin system](https://www.drupal.org/node/2038271) will be applied to Drupal 8.x.3, the code I wrote will probably need to be changed, if the change is not going to be backward-compatible.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @apaderno there is a `FileTransfer` class, however, it performs uploads **only**.
@see https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2011-05-24/filetransferftp-error

Upload example (not tested)

```php
use Drupal\Core\FileTransfer\FileTransferException;

$info = drupal_get_filetransfer_info();

if (empty($info['ftp'])) {
  \Drupal::messenger()->addError('FTP php extension not available.');
  return;
}
$class = $info['ftp']['class'];
$ftp = $class::factory(DRUPAL_ROOT, [
  'advanced' => [
    'hostname' => 'ftp.my.site.com',
  ],
  'username' => 'myusername',
  'username' => 'mypassword',
  'port' => 21,
]);
try {
  // Uploads - @see ftp_put().
  // Where local is inside $jail which is $class::factory($jail, [...]);
  // Where remote is `ftp.my.site.com/path/to/remote/file/name.txt`.
  $ftp->copyFile('/path/to/local/file/name.txt', '/path/to/remote/file/name.txt');
}
catch (FileTransferException $e) {
  \Drupal::messenger()->addError($e->getMessage());
}
```

Sample download - tested (to a variable so binary / text)

```php
use Drupal\Core\FileTransfer\FileTransferException;

$info = drupal_get_filetransfer_info();

if (empty($info['ftp'])) {
  \Drupal::messenger()->addError('FTP php extension not available.');
  return;
}

$class = $info['ftp']['class'];
$ftp = $class::factory(DRUPAL_ROOT, [
  'advanced' => [
    'hostname' => 'ftp.my.site.com',
  ],
  'username' => 'myusername',
  'username' => 'mypassword',
  'port' => 21,
]);
$data = NULL;
try {
  // Login, throws exception if login error, else defines `$ftp->connection`.
  $ftp->connect();
  // Optional - set passive connection..
  ftp_pasv($ftp->connection, TRUE);
  ob_start();
  $result = ftp_get($ftp->connection, 'php://output', '/path/to/remote/file/name.txt', FTP_BINARY);
  $data = ob_get_contents();
  // File size if needed.
  // @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47240733/5150644
  $datasize = ob_get_length();
  ob_end_clean();
  ftp_close($ftp->connection);
}
catch (FileTransferException $e) {
  \Drupal::messenger()->addError($e->getMessage());
}
// Do something with the date, e.g. save it.
if ($data) {
  file_put_contents('public://myfile.txt');
}
```